# Extract keywords from links

Tags: python, regex, keyword-search

I'm trying to extract the first `2` numbers in links like these:

```
https://primer.text.com/sdfg/8406758680-345386743-DSS1-S%20Jasd%12Odsfr%12Iwetds-Osdgf/ 
https://primer.text.com/sdfg/8945879094-849328844-DPE-S%20Jsdfe%12OIert-Isdfu/
https://primer.text.com/sdfg/8493093053-292494834-QW23%23Wsdfg%23Iprf%64Uiojn%32Asdfg-Werts/
```

The output should be like this:

```
id1 = ['8406758680', '8945879094','8493093053']
id2 = ['345386743', '849328844', '292494834']
```

I'm trying to do this using the `re` module.

Please, tell me how to do it.

This the code snippet I have so far:

```
def GetUrlClassId(UrlInPut):
    ClassID = ''
    for i in UrlInPut:
        if i.isdigit():
            ClassID+=i
        elif ClassID !='':
            return int(ClassID)
    return ""

def GetUrlInstanceID(UrlInPut):
    InstanceId = ''
    ClassID = 0
    for i in UrlInPut:
        if i.isdigit() and ClassID==1:
            InstanceId+=i
        elif InstanceId !='':
            return int(InstanceId)
        if i == '-':
            ClassID+=1
    return ""
```

I don't want to use something like this. I would like to use regular expressions.

Comment: Are these IDs of fixed length/ fixed position? Does look like this in the example. In that case you could just slice the string. Otherwise RegEx is probably the goto solution.

Comment: The first ID must be 10 digits long and the second ID must be 9 digits long

Comment: And it will always start after this `https://primer.text.com/sdfg/` (29 chars long)? So starting at position 29?

Comment: Yes, the link always starts with https://primer.text.com/sdfg/

Comment: Since they are fixed lengths, you can simply use something like `/(\d{10})-(\d{9})-` as your regular expression

Comment: Either use RegEx as @accdias proposed or `[firstId, secondId] = "https://primer.text.com/sdfg/8406758680-345386743"[29:49].split("-")`. You will then have the IDs in variable `firstId` and `secondId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex pattern: `/(\d{10})-(\d{9})` the brackets are needed to identify the groups of digits, the `{}` specifies an exact occurrence of a repetition, [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
# urls separated by a white space
urls = 'https://primer.text.com/sdfg/8406758680-345386743-DSS1-S%20Jasd%12Odsfr%12Iwetds-Osdgf/ https://primer.text.com/sdfg/8945879094-849328844-DPE-S%20Jsdfe%12OIert-Isdfu/ https://primer.text.com/sdfg/8493093053-292494834-QW23%23Wsdfg%23Iprf%64Uiojn%32Asdfg-Werts/'

urls = urls.split() # as list

import re

ids = [re.search(r'/(\d{10})-(\d{9})', url).groups() for url in urls]
print(list(zip(*ids)))
```

Output

```
[('8406758680', '8945879094', '8493093053'), ('345386743', '849328844', '292494834')]
```

Answer (score 0):

With Regex, you can do a literal match on the base URL, and then capture two groups of multiple digits using `\d+` (`\d` matches 0-9, `+` matches at least one of the proceeding group). `re.findall` returns a list of matching groups.

```
import re
l1 = "https://primer.text.com/sdfg/8406758680-345386743-DSS1-S%20Jasd%12Odsfr%12Iwetds-Osdgf/"
l2 = "https://primer.text.com/sdfg/8945879094-849328844-DPE-S%20Jsdfe%12OIert-Isdfu/"
l3 = "https://primer.text.com/sdfg/8493093053-292494834-QW23%23Wsdfg%23Iprf%64Uiojn%32Asdfg-Werts/"

for l in [l1, l2, l3]:
  result = re.findall(r'https://primer.text.com/sdfg/(\d+)-(\d+)', l)
  print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('8406758680', '345386743')]
[('8945879094', '849328844')]
[('8493093053', '292494834')]
```

From here, reformatting into your desired data structure should be simple enough (use `zip` or something).